# cannot find gamepad in Supertuxkart

Tags: gamepad, xbox-360

I have installed xboxdrv and jstest-gtk. I connected my gamepad (copy of Xbox 360) and ran:

```
sudo xboxdrv -s
```

It finds the gamepads:

> Your Xbox/Xbox360 controller should now be available as:
>    /dev/input/js1
>    /dev/input/event18

The gamepad is listed and I can try out all axis and buttons when I run:

```
jstest-gtk
```

While xboxdrv is still running I launch Supertuxkart from the menu but I do not find the gamepad in the "Options --> Controls".

What do I miss? Any idea?

Xpad is not loaded in my Ubuntu 18.04. I will try tomorrow to purge xboxdrv and load xpad instead.